# Sassの@importとSprocketsのrequire, require_treeの使い分けは？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

Railsで開発している場合Sassを使って開発する場面も多いかと思います。

Sassには`@import`がありますが、
Railsには`Sprockets`もあります。

`Sprockets`の`require`や`require_tree`と**CSSをまとめる**という最終目的は同じように思います。

使い分けのベストプラクティスはあるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

基本的にSassを使うなら、Sassのファイルに関しては`@import`でファイルをロードするのが無難と思います。
Railsガイドに[それに関する記載](http://railsguides.jp/asset_pipeline.html#%E3%83%9E%E3%83%8B%E3%83%95%E3%82%A7%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%81%A8%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%83%AC%E3%82%AF%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E3%83%96)もあります。

> Sassファイルを複数使用しているのであれば、Sprocketsディレクティブで読み込まずにSass
>   @importルールを使用する必要があります。このような場合にSprocketsディレクティブを使用してしまうと、Sassファイルが自分自身のスコープに置かれるため、その中で定義されている変数やミックスインが他のSassから利用できなくなってしまいます。